# Is it possible to move the position of Action.ShowCard's new Adaptive Card?

Tags: spfx, adaptive-cards, spfx-extension

I am using "Action.ShowCard" to show another card in adaptive cards - specifically spfx ACE in the Viva Connections Dashboard.

I cannot see a way to get the new card to appear anywhere other than the bottom of the parent card. Is it possible to get it to appear somewhere else? Ideally I would like some more content under the button that calls "Action.ShowCard".

For example, if you look at the simple examples here: https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.ShowCard.html you will see that the new adaptive card that is shown to the user always appears at the bottom. This is OK when there is not much content on the parent card, but when the parent card has a lot of content then the user experience is not so good as they miss the new content at the bottomn of the card.

[image: Action.ShowCard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in Preview mode, you would single click to expand the card. When editing, you need to double click the `Action.ShowCard` button to have it display its associated fields. Then, you can add the additional actions, etc., that you want.

[image]

Comment: I didn't have any issue adding the Action anywhere else in the adaptive card, either. I could drag it above or below as well as add other elements.

Comment: Maybe compare what you are wanting to do against this other Adaptive Cards sample: [Show card wizard sample](https://adaptivecardsci.z5.web.core.windows.net/pr/7941/samples/ShowCardWizard.html)

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for the quick response. Showing me how to use the designer properly for Action.ShowCard is the piece I was missing.